# Keep the UITabBar visible

Tags: swift, tvos

On the Apple Tv when you choose a tab bar item the tab bar disappears until you bring it into focus again by scrolling up. Is there a way to not hide the tab bar and keep it visible the entire time?

Comment: I'm not sure how it works with TvOS, but with iOS, in the storyboard there should be an `On Swipe` feature in the Attributes inspector of the navigation controller, make sure that it is unchecked.

Comment: Its unchecked so it doesn't seem to work the same way.

Comment: I'm sorry. I wish I could help.